# Couchbase nodes are stuck in pending after bucket creation, nodes aren't rebalancing

Tags: azure, cache, session, couchbase

If anyone here is familiar with setting up Couchbase, I need your help. I'm in the process of migrating all of our on-prem servers to Azure. Right now we're trying to get Couchbase in the cloud to manage session state. However, when we set up a cluster and add nodes to it, the nodes immediately fail and are stuck in a pending state. We can't rebalance the nodes. Whenever we try to uninstall and reinstall Couchbase, the same thing happens. All the nodes are on the same virtual network and Windows Firewall is disabled on each node.

When I create a new bucket the system logs: Service 'memcached' exited with status -1073740940. Restarting.

Whenever I try to rebalance, the system logs: Rebalance exited with reason {not_all_nodes_are_ready_yet}.

Our OS for each node is Windows Server 2016, and our Couchbase version is 4.1 Community edition. We have three nodes.

Comment: EDIT: It appears that when our web servers hit the couchbase cluster, that's when everything goes to shit and the nodes fail. I changed the config files to point elsewhere elsewhere and the servers are stable. It's only when we start using the website to test that the cluster goes offline.

But the web servers we have in azure are migrated from on-prem, so all the code and packages should be the same save for the config files which we've changed.

Comment: Do the Azure VMs have the same (or better) specs as your on-premises nodes (e.g. RAM, CPU, etc)?

Comment: They have better specs.